# APscheduler will not stop

Tags: python, python-2.7, application-shutdown, apscheduler

I have python code that I am developing for a website that, among other things, creates an excel sheet and then converts it into a json file. I need for this code to run continuously unless it is killed by the website administrator.

To this end, I am using APscheduler.

The code runs perfectly without APscheduler but when I attempt to add the rest of the code one of two things happens; 1) It runs forever and will not stop despite using "ctrl+C" and I need to stop it using task manager or 2) It only runs once, and then it stops

Code That doesn't Stop:

```
from apscheduler.scheduler import Scheduler
import logging
import time

logging.basicConfig()
sched = Scheduler()
sched.start()

(...)
code to make excel sheet and json file
(...)

@sched.interval_schedule(seconds = 15)
def job():
    excelapi_final()

while True:
    time.sleep(10)
sched.shutdown(wait=False)
```

Code that stops running after one time:

```
from apscheduler.scheduler import Scheduler
import logging
import time

logging.basicConfig()
sched = Scheduler()

(...)
#create excel sheet and json file
(...)

@sched.interval_schedule(seconds = 15)
def job():
    excelapi_final()
sched.start()

while True:
    time.sleep(10)
    sched.shutdown(wait=False)
```

I understand from other questions, a few tutorials and the documentation that `sched.shutdown` should allow for the code to be killed by ctrl+C - however that is not working. Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the **standalone** mode:

```
sched = Scheduler(standalone=True)
```

and then start the scheduler like this:

```
try:
    sched.start()
except (KeyboardInterrupt):
    logger.debug('Got SIGTERM! Terminating...')
```

Your corrected code should look like this:

```
from apscheduler.scheduler import Scheduler
import logging
import time

logging.basicConfig()
sched = Scheduler(standalone=True)

(...)
code to make excel sheet and json file
(...)

@sched.interval_schedule(seconds = 15)
def job():
    excelapi_final()

try:
    sched.start()
except (KeyboardInterrupt):
    logger.debug('Got SIGTERM! Terminating...')
```

This way the program will stop when **Ctrl-C** is pressed

Comment: Thank you! I got it to work with a minor edit: `try: sched.start () except (KeyboardInterrupt): sched.shutdown(wait=False)`. Also, do you know why the previous code did not work?

Comment: In the first case, the while loop was executing forever so the sched.shutdown was never called. In the second case, with the first iteration of the while loop, the program was paused for 10 seconds, and right after the sched was shutdown.

Answer (score 1):

You can gracefully shut it down:

```
import signal
from apscheduler.scheduler import Scheduler
import logging
import time

logging.basicConfig()
sched = Scheduler()

(...)
#create excel sheet and json file
(...)

@sched.interval_schedule(seconds = 15)
def job():
    excelapi_final()

sched.start()

def gracefully_exit(signum, frame):
    print('Stopping...')
    sched.shutdown()

signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, gracefully_exit)
signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, gracefully_exit)
```

Comment: For me, this is the solution that worked (though it would seem that in the latest version of the module apscheduler.scheduler and Scheduler no longer exist).